ArgoCD GitOps declarative config: How to store repo creds in a secure manner in git?
ArgoCD supports declarative configuration: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/
In particular, for repository credentials: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/argocd-repo-creds-yaml/
For example, a typical entry might look like this:
# Repository credentials, for using the same credentials in multiple repositories.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: argoproj-https-creds
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repo-creds
stringData:
  url: https://github.com/argoproj
  type: helm
  password: my-password
  username: my-username

Likewise, it's possible to add SSH-based access for git repositories with a private SSH key:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: argoproj-ssh-creds
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repo-creds
stringData:
  url: git@github.com:argoproj-labs
  type: helm
  sshPrivateKey: |
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

In both scenarios the plain-text password and the private ssh key get stored in a plain text file in git.
Is there a canonical way to store these credentials in a secure manner, instead of plain text?
https://xyproblem.info/: I am trying to solve the problem of bootstrapping an ArgoCD instance via a couple of YAML files stored in a git repository meant for gitops in an automated fashion. The ArgoCD application server would consume the repo-creds YAML file to populate itself, so that it can subsequently create ArgoCD applications from these repositories. However it's not desirable to have the password / private key be checked into git as plain text. How can we bootstrap all the needed repositories without doing so?
I am aware of at least one workaround: I could use the argocd CLI app in our K8s cluster to populate the repo-creds (or even plain kubectl apply for that matter). But then, what is the point of ArgoCD to programmatically support repo-creds credentials via gitops?

You might want to add a way to inject secrets, and avoid storing them in git indeed.
Here are some common solution to inject the secrets, and just have the secret custom resources in git:

SOPS
Sealed Secrets
Doppler
External Secrets

A clean bootstrap of argocd would then look like this:

Install the secret operator on your cluster
Apply the argocd manifests with the operator custom resource for the secret containing your repo-creds

So usually at bootstrap you still end up providing 1 key which is not in git, the one the secret operator needs.
Note: A really useful feature is the credentials template, as it allows you to define 1 secret for your Git repositories, instead of repeating the configuration for each repo.

I'd like to recommend against anything like SOPS that encrypts content in your repository, because this makes it difficult to sanely respond to a compromised key (because even if you re-encrypt things, a compromised key can be used with the prior data in your git history). +1 for External Secrets.
